# How do I convert an entire website to a string that I can parse using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, string, api, parsing

So I am making a website for my video game servers and our admin tool outputs the current server status as a .json in a giant string of text to this url:

http://server.bandwidthbandits.org/api/status

I want to take the entire string from the url and assign it to a var so I can use JSON.parse() with the string obtained from the link. In other words how do I convert the entire aforementioned web page into a long string I can parse with javascript?

I have no idea how to do that, but I'm pretty sure I can parse the JSON once it's in a string.

This is what I thought might work, but it didn't:

```
p id="SERVERS">HELLO</p>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var txt = document.getElementsByTagName('http://server.bandwidthbandits.org/api/status')[0].innerHTML;
    var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
    document.getElementById("SERVERS").innerHTML = obj.name + ", " + obj.map + ", " + obj.gamemode + ", " + obj.players; 
    //more parsing necessary, but to tired to write full statement right now
</script>
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
<p id="name">HELLO</p>
<p id="maxp">HELLO</p>
<p id="curp">HELLO</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function FetchAPI(url) {
        fetch(url).then(function (data) {
            return data.json();
        }).then(function (obj1) {
            console.log(obj1);
        });
    }

    var nukestats = FetchAPI("http://server.bandwidthbandits.org/api/status/340417768");
    obj = JSON.parse(nukestats);

    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = 'Server name: ' + (obj[0].name);
    document.getElementById("maxp").innerHTML = 'Max Players: ' + (obj[0].maxPlayers);
    document.getElementById("curp").innerHTML = 'Current Players: ' + (obj[0].currentPlayers);
</script>
```

The updated code shows what I tried to do. Since there will be multiple servers that I will have to query I tried to make the fetching of the API into a function. The problem I face is that I don't know how to import the API from the web into something I know how to parse through. If I copy and paste the API output into my code as a variable it works, but it does not work when I try to import the API using java script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data from the site and using promises, parse it:

```
fetch("http://yourapi.com").then(function (data) {
    return data.json();
}).then(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

What you are looking at is not an actual website by the way. The API returns a json string and since the browser can't really do anything else with it, it will just display it as text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get response using ajax call with data type application/Json

Or Directly use below jquery method:

```
 $.getJSON(url,function(data){
//Here you get json on data variable
});
```

But make sure your url will return json string.